# Randomize a string input into all possibilities

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help making a program that takes a string using args and randomizes it into every possibility. The program's results would then be saved into a text file provided by the user when executing the program.

Comment: Unless your string is very short, there are going to be too many possibilities for it to be practical to list them all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

If you need *all* of the possible permutations in a random order, then I would suggest building then shuffling a list:

```
from itertools import permutations
from random import shuffle

def shuffled_permutations(s):
    perms = list(permutations(s)) # create all permutations
    shuffle(perms) # shuffle the list randomly
    return ["".join(p) for p in perms] # rebuild strings and return
```

Applying this function:

```
>>> shuffled_permutations("ABC")
['BCA', 'CBA', 'BAC', 'ABC', 'ACB', 'CAB']
```

If you don't really need the permutations in a random order (i.e. you just want to know what they all are), it is much more efficient to use `permutations` directly, e.g.

```
for p in permutations(s):
```

**Note** that, for a string `len(s) == n`, the length of all permutations is `n!` (e.g. for `n == 5`, `(5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1) == 120`); this gets long pretty fast (there are 3,628,800 permutations of my user name, for example).

Comment: To make it more effiecient, turn this function into a generator and drop the shuffle method

Comment: Then you can just call `permutations` directly! But if the OP doesn't need the `shuffle` that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function:

```
def permutations(word):
    if len(word) == 1:
        return [word]

    perms = permutations(word[1:])
    char = word[0]
    result = []

    for perm in perms:
        for i in range(len(perm) + 1):
            result.append(perm[:i] + char + perm[i:])
    return result
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].